# How to solve Qt Unresolved error code 0x80040216?

Tags: c++, qt, audio, cross-platform

I am a student writing a project using Qt. I need to play an audio file when the button is pushed, so I write the code:

```
void DrumsWindow::on_pushButton_dHH_clicked()
{
    m_player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    m_playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(m_player);

    m_player->setPlaylist(m_playlist);
    m_playlist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("sound/HH.wav"));

    m_player->play();
}
```

But when I hit the pushbutton, it doesn't work, an error occures:

```
DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code 0x80040216 ()
```

Please, help me! What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: I was told to do the task without using resource files. Of course, this code works:

```
void DrumsWindow::on_pushButton_dHH_clicked()
{
    m_player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    m_playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(m_player);

    m_player->setPlaylist(m_playlist);
    m_playlist->addMedia(QUrl("qrc:/aud/sound/HH.wav"));

    m_player->play();
}
```

But I'm not allowed to use this way.

Answer (score 2):

You should write your complete file directory to solve the problem. Alternatively you can receive the song path from file browser or a `QLineEdit` filled by user.

**Update**
You can use QDir::currentPath() to find your current directory (executing directory) and move wherever you want.

```
void DrumsWindow::on_pushButton_dHH_clicked()
{
    QString filePath = QDir::currentPath();
    m_player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    m_playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(m_player);

    m_player->setPlaylist(m_playlist);
    m_playlist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(filePath + "/sound/HH.wav"));

    m_player->play();
}
```

Also move your creating code of m_player and m_playlist to the constructor to prevent memory leak in your application.

```
    m_player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    m_playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(m_player);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But I'm not allowed to use absolute paths and resource files... Maybe, there's another way? Or another Qt library for playing sound?

Comment: What do you can to do? can you receive the path from client? is there any specific location to find songs from there? Like music folder in OS?

Comment: I have a folder "sound" where there are all the music files. And I need to play music from there. This folder is on the same level as my project files

Comment: Your sound folder is beside executing file? or can be?

Comment: I have a folder "sem_prj": in this folder there are the executables and the sound folder

Comment: So the executables are one level higher than the sound files

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please show how should I use it in my code?

Comment: Print filePath and make sure it is the correct directory for your songs after adding /sound/HH.wav

Comment: It works perfectly with an absolute path, but doesn't work this way :(

Comment: I've updated the answer, also I've checked and it's working.

Comment: @Farshid616 maybe update your answer with the issue of the original code that m_player and m_playlist objects are being created everytime the slot is called (without deletion if already created) which leads to leaking memory. Creation could be moved to class constructor.